# Overriding templates with Django 3.2.6

Tags: python, django, templates

I am new to python and working through a Zero to Hero course by Mosh on YouTube. I am getting stuck on a problem, and even after going through all the Django documents (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/overriding-templates/) I just can't see where I am going wrong. I have tried pasting the file path for the base.html file directly, as well as other methods such as `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')`  to try find the right path. But I still get an error.

Here is what I think all the code someone would need to understand the problem. Sorry if I have copied too much, but I am not sure what I actually need to show for someone to fully understand where I might have gone wrong.

The overall project is call `PyShop` and I have a file called `index.html` which is located in `PyShop\products\templates\index.html` which is trying to call the `base.html` file by `{% extends 'base.html' %}`. The `base.html` file is located here `PyShop\templates\base.html`.

When I run I get the below error. If I move the `base.html` file out from under the `templates` folder and just have it on it's own like this `PyShop\base.html` ie not in any subfolder then it works no problem.

`TemplateDoesNotExist at /products/`

Here is the `PyShop\pyshop\settings.py` file in which I have the directories etc for the web app.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/



# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'products.apps.ProductsConfig',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'pyshop.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Thanks for taking the time to look at it, it might be a pretty trivial mistake but I've no idea why it isn't working.

Comment: The errors page shows you all the places where the template is looked for.

Comment: Ok so, I swear I did look through the errors page before posting this! But since then I had to head home and this morning when I relaunched the project it works now. I honestly have no idea why! But it works now. Thanks for taking the time to help out anyway!